# select all SASS files

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I want to select all the SASS files in my project with gulp.

I tried this :

```
gulp.src('/**/*.scss')
```

this didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a dot before the slash, like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Comment: src works it returns "dev/sass/style.scss" like it should but the dest got messed up it should return "dist/css" but instead it's returning "dist/css/dev/sass/style.css"

Comment: What you are setting in your dest?

Comment: .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));